# How can a given length of something yield different sum in square meters?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can a rope of say 100 meters yield different return in square meters, based on how you divide each side?

E.g.

10m x 10m = 100m2
15m x 5m = 75m2

Now of course I see that based on how you choose the sides the result may vary because of how multiplication works.

But since square meters is a measurement for the size of a room I can't see how the same length of something really CREATES different sized rooms when stretched to its fullest.

Comment: this is probably measurement theory ... not measure theory

Answer (score 1):

The area of a rectangle with length $l$ and width $w$ is $A = lw$.

Let a rectangle have fixed perimeter $P = 2(l + w)$.  Solving for $w$ yields

\begin{align*}
P & = 2(l + w)\\
\frac{P}{2} & = l + w\\
\frac{P}{2} - l & = w
\end{align*}

Thus, the area can be expressed as a function of the length.

\begin{align*}
A(l) & = l\left(\frac{P}{2} - l\right) && \text{substitute $\dfrac{P}{2} - l$ for $w$}\\
     & = \frac{P}{2}l - l^2 && \text{distribute}\\
     & = -l^2 + \frac{P}{2}l && \text{addition is commutative}\\
     & = -\left(l^2 - \frac{P}{2}l\right) && \text{factor}\\
     & = -\left(l^2 - \frac{P}{2}l + \frac{P^2}{16}\right) + \frac{P^2}{16} && \text{complete the square}\\
     & = -\left(l - \frac{P}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{P^2}{16} && \text{factor}
\end{align*}

The area is defined if $0 < l < P/2$.  The square of the term in parentheses is non-negative, so the area is at most $P^2/16$, which can only occur if $l = P/4$.  Note that if $l = P/4$, then $w = P/2 - l = P/2 - P/4 = P/4$, so the rectangle of fixed perimeter $P$ with maximum area is a square.

For other values of $l$ in the domain of the area function, the square of the term in parentheses is positive, so the area is less than $P^2/16$. As $l$ increases from $P/4$, the term in parentheses gets larger, so the area of the rectangle gets smaller, as you can see by counting the unit squares in the three rectangles with perimeter $16$ units shown below.

[image: rectangles_with_the_same_perimeter_but_different_areas]

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows how the dimensions and shape of the perimeter matter: in other words, for a given length $L$ of perimeter, the area $A$ can vary.

See if you can guess shape of perimeter for a given length maximizes the area. In general, it can be shown that 
$$L^2 \geq 4\pi A$$

For the perimeter that maximizes area $A$, $L^2 = 4\pi A$.

Comment: I understand that. I just don't see how the area gets affected. How can a 12 meter rope yield different areas based on which shape. Sure I can follow the formulas and all, It's just mindboggling for me. One would think the amount of space would be the same no matter shape if and only if the rope is stretched.

Comment: It's one of the reasons we study mathematics to improve our intuition. With the same $40$ meter length of rope of your original question, you can run it up and down in a straight line $20$ meters long and and enclose a shape of zero area. Still waiting for you to tell me what shape with $40$ maximizes area! ;-)